# Image not being correctly removed with checkbox selection

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having difficulty removing an image URL from a MySQL table with the use of a checkbox, if a user decides they no longer want an image (avatar) to be used on their profile.

The table (it has more columns) looks like:

```
user_id | img                                    | user_name
 1      |  http://www.domain.com/path/to/image   |  User A
 2      |                                        |  User B
 3      |                                        |  User C
```

On the user profiles, if a URL exists in img, then the image properly shows.

My HTML form looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="user/update_info.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user_name">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="user_name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="password" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <input type="file" name="img">
    <br>
    <label for="noav">Use no avatar.</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="noav" name="noav" value="Yes">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Update">
</form>
```

My PHP file looks like:

```
<?php
$user_id = $_SESSION["user"]['user_id'];
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$noav = $_POST['noav'];
$session_password = $_SESSION["user"]['password'];

if ($password != $session_password) {
  $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}
$img = $_FILES["img"];
$query = "UPDATE users 
          SET user_name='$user_name', char_name='$char_name',
              user_email='$email', password='$password'
          WHERE user_id=$user_id";
mysqli_query($this->connection, $query)
  or die("Update error: " . mysqli_error($this->connection));
if($img["error"] == 0) {
  $name = "public/gallery/" . time() . $img["name"];
  $name_in_db = URL . $name;
  $tmp_name = $img["tmp_name"];
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,  $name);
  if ($noav = 'Yes') {
    $query = "UPDATE users SET img='' WHERE user_id=$user_id";
  } else {
    $query = "UPDATE users SET img='$name_in_db' WHERE user_id=$user_id";
  }
mysqli_query($this->connection, $query)
  or die("Update error: " . mysqli_error($this->connection));
}
?>
```

Before I added in the "noav" checkbox, variable, and if check (only the bottom query existed), everything functioned properly.

Adding in the "noav" stuff essentially broke it.  Now, no matter what, if the checkbox is checked or not, and if an image is selected or not, it clears the img column for that user, making no img whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this `if ($noav = 'Yes')`

You're assigning instead of comparing:

```
if ($noav == 'Yes')
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Plus, it's best to check if the checkbox is set using `isset()`.

Also make sure the session was started; that is unknown.

If it wasn't, add `session_start();` inside all your files using them.

You're also open to a serious SQL injection. Use a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: It's all part of a user class (I just removed some of the parts that didn't relate as much, such as the sessions and statements).  After changing it to "==" from "=", it does work, however, it will only clear it if an image is selected and the checkbox is selected.  When only the checkbox is selected, the old URL is staying.

Comment: Nevermind!  I figured it out!  After moving the query to clear the img outside of the img error check, it works out perfectly fine.  Thank you very much.  Made sure to select your answer as the correct one.